# the data types varchar and varchar are incompatible in the subtraction operator c# web service

Tags: c#, web-services, windows-forms-designer

Currently i use five layers and in my Business layer I've one method for then call him  into my Web Service but I can't make a subtraction

```
public void ActualizarStock(ConsultaStock consultaStock, int cantidad_salida)
{
    this.configurarConexion();
    this.Conec.CadenaSQL = "UPDATE Consulta_stock "
                           + " SET cantidad = '" + consultaStock.Cantidad.ToString() + "' - '"
                           + cantidad_salida.ToString()
                           + "' WHERE sku = '" + consultaStock.Sku + "';";
    this.Conec.EsSelect = true;
    this.Conec.conectar();
}
```

Comment: Uh, yeah... you can't subtract strings. Why are you even trying to?

Comment: The parameters are int in my database and in the classes, how can I convert to int?

Comment: The character `'` in SQL is used as a string type delimiter.

Comment: Depending on what is the value of `consultaStock.Sku` you could have a SQL Injection vulnerability

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this:

```
this.Conec.CadenaSQL = "UPDATE Consulta_stock "
                           + " SET cantidad = " + consultaStock.Cantidad.ToString() + " - "
                           + cantidad_salida.ToString()
                           + " WHERE sku = '" + consultaStock.Sku + "';";
```

or why not:

```
this.Conec.CadenaSQL = "UPDATE Consulta_stock "
                           + " SET cantidad = " + (consultaStock.Cantidad - cantidad_salida).ToString()
                           + " WHERE sku = '" + consultaStock.Sku + "';";
```

Comment: Successfully, was very easy... damn single quotes. THAAAANKS

Answer (score 0):

The `'` character in SQL is used a a string delimiter, you could do de calculation before the query or just get rid of the `'`.

For example:

```
public void ActualizarStock(ConsultaStock consultaStock, int cantidad_salida)
{
    int nuevoStock = consultaStock.Cantidad - cantidad_salida;
    this.configurarConexion();
    this.Conec.CadenaSQL = "UPDATE Consulta_stock SET cantidad = " + nuevoStock.ToString() + " WHERE sku = '" + consultaStock.Sku + "';";
    this.Conec.EsSelect = true;
    this.Conec.conectar();
}
```